# Android Eclipse not launching app with google-play-services_lib

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am doing a test app that requires GCM (google cloud messaging) I am calling this:

```
GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
```

So, for that , I added the google-play-services_lib in my workspace , and added it to my main project's build path.

Whenever I am trying to run the main project, I get this error :

> [2015-05-08 12:21:37 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Java heap
>   space [2015-05-08 12:21:37 - gcmtester] Conversion to Dalvik format
>   failed: Unable to execute dex: Java heap space

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding, restarting eclipse, my pc, etc.

My target SDK is Android 5.1.1, and I have a physical device where I am debugging, which runs 5.0.1

After reaching 99% in progress, the launching get stuck, and after a few minutes, I get the heap space error.

Comment: Why am I getting down votes ?Is my question not valid ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as yours. I have deleted that library from my workspace. And removed reference from my project.

And again created a fresh copy of the library and added the reference to my project and every thing has worked.

Comment: yes, I added the library project, as well as the jar. (both separately)  . It failed both times. Btw, how much RAM does this require ?  I have XmX set to 500mb

Comment: 512 will be fine. In my case i have 512 mb dedicated to that and its work.